# CodeIgniter: How to set session and/or controller variables in hooksr?

Tags: php, codeigniter

So I'm having trouble making my hooks actually do anything. I'd like to set a few session variables before views are rendered every time. I have put this in my config/hooks.php:

```
$hook['post_controller_constructor'] = array(
    'class'    => 'Permissions',
    'function' => 'can_view',
    'filename' => 'pre_hooks.php',
    'filepath' => 'hooks');
```

I've also enabled hooks in the config file:

```
$config['enable_hooks'] = TRUE;
```

The code I'm trying to make work:

```
<?php
class Permissions {
    var $CI;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->CI = &get_instance();
        $this->CI->load->library("session");
    }

    public function can_view(){
        $this->CI->session->set_userdata('test','test');
    }
}
```

A simple echo of the session variable doesn't work, but when I set the session variable in a controller, it works...

Comment: Doesnt Class Permissions have to extend something?

Answer (score 1):

Not showing some controller's code, but if you are loading session library twice, in hook and controllers code, may be the second load reinitializes the $this->CI->session. CI takes care of not load twice, but initialices in each attempt. 
You can check if double load is happening by enabling logs, you will find a message warning you of that.

Please try autoloading the session lib.

Comment: I tried auto-loading and taken out the loading from both the config & controller, but no change...

Comment: Please enable loggin and check if there is any message

Comment: I enabled logging but there and the hooks class initializes but it does no calls to the hooks class are made.

Comment: I asked you to enable loggin because if there is a double attemp to load session lib, a warning should be recorded.